# How to Read Java card Image Number(CIN) within Applet

Tags: uniqueidentifier, javacard, uid

I am new to java card development.i want to read UID within Applet.then there is no way to read card UID within Applet.then i read Global platform documentation.they say that there is a unique key called Card Image number(CIN).I don't know anything about CIN and i used jcop 31(2.1.1) java card for development.can anyone tell me how to use CIN and what is main difference between UID and CIN.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know about CIN, but if you are looking at a unique number within Global Platform then the CPLC data is often used.